# how to change backcolor of the countrol in infragistics control windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, infragistics

I am having the requirement of changing back color of the Infragistics i have created a new ultracheckeditor and added to panel now when I try to change the back color of the ultracheckeditor to panel color i am unable change the color

```
appearance1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
appearance1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.ultrabutton.Apperance=apperance1;
```

[ImageSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYkWL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can due to AppStyling used in the container by setting UseAppStyling to false worked:

```
this.ultrabutton.UseAppStyling = false;
```

If this and the aforementioned UseOsThemes settings do not help, be sure that the button is not rendered using a bitmap image. If that's the case, you'll need to address the problem by have different-colored versions of the bitmap or, if transparency was used, you can change the color behind the rendered bitmap so that it shows through as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Apperance property and make sure the UseOsThemes property is False:

```
ultraButton1.UseOsThemes = DefaultableBoolean.False;
ultraButton1.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
```